# How to avoid valgrind (or other memcheck tools) misreporting when I initialize a struct which contain a dynamic array?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I want to initialize a struct which contains a dynamic array, I wrote all this stuff in a function. And there is another function for cleaning this struct, theoretically, there will be no memory leaks. However, when I run the program with valgrind, it report that there was memory leaks when at the entry or init function.

Firstly, I wrote this init function with malloc to allocate memory for this struct. It report memory leak.

Then, I change malloc to realloc(NULL, ...) to avoid this misreport but I failed.

I don't know what the standard way in C is to implement this function.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum
{
    RUN_SUCCESS,
    /*Failure*/
    RUN_FAILURE
} RunStat;

typedef struct
{
    char *elements;
    size_t top;
    size_t size;
} Stack;

RunStat init_stack(Stack *stack)
{
    stack->elements = (char *)realloc(NULL, 100 * sizeof(char));
    stack->size = 100;
    stack->top = 0;
    return RUN_SUCCESS;
}

RunStat free_stack(Stack *stack)
{
    free(stack->elements);
    stack->elements = NULL;
    stack->size = 0;
    stack->top = 0;
    return RUN_SUCCESS;
}


int main ()
{
    Stack stack;
    init_stack(&stack);
    free_stack(&stack);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Every memory here is under my control, I want to make this struct initialized without any memory leak warning. And I want to know the standard way to do that.

Comment: Valgrind analyzes the actual behavior of your program, not your source code.  If it says you have a leak, it's a pretty darn good bet that you have a leak.

Comment: Please include a complete program that can be compiled and run, showing the memory leak issue.

Comment: ^^ Indeed.  Very likely the problem is not inherent in these functions themselves, but rather arises from how you use them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, code updated.

Comment: and what exactly does it complain about?

Comment: You now have presented a complete and pretty minimal program, but it does not reproduce the error.  Valgrind does not detect any leaks in it, at least not for me.